# header charset. where does it come from?

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding, nginx, http-headers

I have a problem with charset in http header. it shows "utf-8":

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Where I can change this to iso-8859-1? I changed default charset in apache and nginx config, but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it's coming from your application instead of apache and nginx. how you call your application, via CGI or fast cgi to php?

Comment: I'm using php as apache module, not cgi. I added 'default_charset = "iso-8859-1"' to /etc/php.ini and it did not change anything.

Comment: Also, I've checked website code and database, but did not find anything related to "utf-8" there.